# How can I unlock my hard disk?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, system-installation, encryption, passphrase

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 all my 500GB HDD as in one drive. I cleared all the data on HDD while installing. But while starting OS, it asks me to enter a passphrase.

With the USB I used to install Ubuntu, I am now trying Ubuntu, here I can see 2 drives, one of 256MB and other of 499GB that has a lock symbol over it (on home  are the words *499GB Encrypted*). On clicking the drive, a window pops up showing

> Enter a passphrase to unlock this volume

I don't understand what this is and am unable to open.

I did not set any such password to the hard drive. I tried the password that I set to log into Ubuntu but that gives the error

> no key exists with that passphrase

What can I do to open my OS in a normal way. Can anyone explain what this problem is and why it occurs?

Comment: It sounds like you enabled encryption when you installed.

Comment: can I disable it now?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you chose to encrypt your Ubuntu installation. When it asks for a passphrase it is asking for your encryption pass.

If this is a new installation and you didn't have a prior version on the HD then just try re-installing  (and make sure not to choose encryption).