# "Please enter passphrase for disk"

Tags: encryption, disk, passphrase

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04. I don't know what has happened; when I start and enter the passphrase, this message appears:

> Please enter passphrase for disk ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (cryptswap1) on none!

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe you should have put encrypt your home folder during installation. Usually the passphrase is the same password to login. If you forgot, take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/q/550486/164660

Comment: Did you recently install Ubuntu? If so, try the password for the account you created while installing.

Comment: Sounds kind of like it wants a passphrase for an encrypted swap... I thought it was supposed to pick it's own random passphrase for swap... something doesn't sound right, maybe look in `/etc/fstab`, and this might be vaguely useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/56843/could-not-mount-dev-mapper-cryptswap1

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/550486/hard-disk-decryption-forgotten-key?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to unlock hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453052/how-to-unlock-hard-disk)

Comment: @SDsolar: That doesn't answer how *boot* from encrypted drives.

Answer (score 1):

If your root partition is not encrypted, or if you're not sure, try this:
Boot off a Ubuntu install DVD or USB stick and select **Try Ubuntu**.

If you are able to see your files, edit /etc/fstab and remove the line that looks like this:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Reboot and it shouldn't ask you for a passphrase.

If you can't see any files then your root partition is encrypted. I personally haven't experienced this issue, so I can't speak with certainty, but the system shouldn't need to access the swap partition to boot... try pushing enter a few times and see if it gives up and continues booting.